# Why do some shell variables have double brackets?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I'm working on linux shell variables and set command.

I have listed all the variables with the set command. Some variables have double brackets as follows.

```
 BASH_CMDS=()
 BASH_LINENO=()
 BASH_SOURCE=()
```

What is the meaning of double brackets? Why does some variable have double parentheses as variable values?

Comment: Google: bash associative array

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses like these are used to initialise [Bash’s indexed and associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). An empty pair of parentheses represents an empty array.

All these variables are described in the Bash documentation: [`BASH_CMDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fCMDS), [`BASH_LINENO`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fLINENO), [`BASH_SOURCE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fSOURCE).